# Add event handler (ExecutionListener or TaskListener) at runtime in Camunda

Tags: java, activiti, business-process-management, camunda

According to Camunda's doc (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-applications/process-application-event-listeners/) a "global" event handler (ExecutionListener or TaskListener) can be added to the `ProcessApplication`. 


Nonetheless, I have not been able to find a way to add a similar ("global") event handler at runtime. This feature was present in Activiti using the method `addEventListener` of the engine's `RuntimeService` (https://www.activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/RuntimeService.html#addEventListener-org.activiti.engine.delegate.event.ActivitiEventListener-) but is no longer present in Camunda's `RuntimeService`.


How could I add a "global" event handler at runtime? 

**Note**: The `ProcessApplication` to which the event handlers will be added can not be modified since I want to add the handlers from a different library.


Thank you all,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The community extension [camunda-bpm-reactor](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-reactor) allows you to register an eventbus that propgates events every time a listener would be triggered. You can then register listeners on those events. So bpmn and listener code are coupled at runtime.

```
@CamundaSelector(type = "userTask", event = TaskListener.EVENTNAME_CREATE)
public class TaskCreateListener implements TaskListener {

   public TaskCreateListener(EventBus eventBus) {
     eventBus.register(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed

Comment: Can i use Spring eventing bridge : 
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.12/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/the-spring-event-bridge/

Comment: Yes. When on Spring Boot, you should prefer the eventing bridge over the reactor extension.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Activiti Method `addEventListener` was added after Camunda forked activiti, that's why the method is not available on Camunda's RuntimeService.

As the documentation said you could define a process application which returns the global execution/task listener. To define a process application at runtime you could use the `EmbeddedProcessApplication` and the `ManagementService#registerProcessApplication` method.

See following example:

```
EmbeddedProcessApplication processApplication = new EmbeddedProcessApplication() {
  public ExecutionListener getExecutionListener() {
    return new ExecutionListener() {
      public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
      // do your stuff       
      }              
    };
  }
};

// register app so that it is notified about events
managementService.registerProcessApplication(deploymentId, processApplication.getReference());
```

Comment: But how do I do if the process application is already defined and initialized? Can I modify the processApplication in order to add the handlers? I would like to add the handlers from a library to an existing app...